# Зачем нужны котроллеры в ASP.NET Core 3.1?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

Зачем в ASP.NET Core 3.1 нужны контроллеры, если маршрутизацию можно настроить в классе `Startup.cs`?
Например у нас есть следующий контроллер, который просто выводит "Hello World!"

```
[HttpGet]
        [Route("Home/Index")]
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return new ContentResult
            {
                Content = "Hello World!"
            };
        }
```

но данного результат можно добиться, просто использовав стандартную маршуртизацию ASP.NET Core

```
                endpoints.MapGet("/", async context =>
                {
                    await context.Response.WriteAsync("Hello World!");
                });
```

Можно добавить целый класс, использовав `app.UseMiddleware()` и получить такой-же результат
Так зачем тогда нужны контроллеры?

Comment: `app.UseMiddleware()` это подключение непосредственного `Middleware`, а не описание `Endpoint`. А отвечая на вопрос - попробуйте включить в `endpoints.MapGet(...)` авторизацию. Причем, мне надо, чтобы авторизация была только на некоторых `Enpoint`'ах.

Comment: В ASP.NET Core можно не использовать контроллеры, если вы используете только архитектуру Razor Pages, то там нет Контроллеров....)))